# Parameterized execution of SQL scripts in Delta Lake

Tags: sql, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake, delta-lake

I have a list of SQL scripts in a text file and delta table. I need to execute them one by one. Delta tables are made. Earlier I was doing through stored procedure using Exec command in SQL server. Any work around for delta lake in databricks??

Comment: what do you mean by execute? where - in notebook, via JDBC/ODBC, something else? what you will do with results?

Comment: I mean I pass a txt file or a table with sql commands and the code executes them one by one

Comment: You would either have to rewrite the queries in the txt file in a notebook, or read the txt file from a notebook and execute the queries if the txt file is not static [see an example here](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/646/is-it-possible-to-read-entire-sql-string-from-file.html)

Comment: Thanks for your  help but the example you gave uses spark sql. Update and merge statement  are not supported on spark sql. I wanted something that does the same to a delta table.

Comment: Isn't [this](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/delta-merge-into.html) what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes I am trying similar to this.  but the issue is the merge statements are not hard coded they have to be passed via a txt file or a Metadata table

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Databricks Notebook](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebooks-manage.html#create-a-notebook) to run sql code or schedule a [job](https://docs.databricks.com/jobs.html) that triggers a specific notebook. If you want to parameterize them you can add [widgets](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/widgets.html) to your notebook as well.